# How can I manage the installation directory with CMake when cross-compiling?

Tags: cmake, cross-platform

I am cross-compiling a C library using CMake and a toolchain file. My toolchain file sets `CMAKE_SYSROOT` to the appropriate value so compilation works with no issues. However, when installing, the library does not install to the directory pointed to by `CMAKE_SYSROOT`. I can achieve that effect by running `make install DESTDIR=xxx` though.

I understand that there are two separate concepts here:

- The cross-compilation toolchain, which consists of binaries that can be run on my local architecture
- The `CMAKE_SYSROOT` which is the root directory of a target-architecture filesystems, containing header files and libraries, passed to e.g. gcc through the `--sysroot` flag.

I have two questions:

- Is it a good idea to conflate the sysroot where my cross-compilation toolchain lives, with the sysroot where all my cross-compiled libraries will be installed? It feels to me like it should be the same, but am not sure, and to CMake it appears they are distinct concepts. **Update:** **answered** in the comments below, these are indeed distinct concepts.
- What is the modern CMake way to specify the installation directory when cross-compiling like described above? **Update:** I believe this should be the same as `CMAKE_SYSROOT`, and I feel CMake should offer a way to only define this once somewhere.

Thanks!

Comment: Typically, you want to install cross-compiled binaries to a location designated for the purpose -- possibly, but not necessarily, a filesystem image for the cross target.  Your cross toolchain consists of *local-system* binaries, so it's not clear why you suppose their cross-binary outputs would belong in the same location as they themselves.

Comment: Of course, this is what I was missing. Thanks. That answers my first bullet.

Comment: Come to think of it, my second is pretty clear now also. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, actually the second bullet is still not clear. I updated my question.

Answer (score 2):

There is **no interference** between sysroot and install directory (prefix).

Sysroot is given by `CMAKE_SYSROOT` variable and denotes prefix for tools used during build process.

Install directory(prefix) is given by `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` variable and denotes the path, where the project will be used upon installation. E.g. with install prefix `/usr/local` the project's executable `foo` expects to be run as `/usr/local/bin/foo`.

Note, that with default installation procedure, CMake installs files to the **host** machine. For install files onto the **target** machine, this procedure is needed to be adjusted. Parameter `DESTDIR=xxx` for `make install` is a way for install files directly to the target machine. Another way is to create a package (e.g. with CPack) on **host**, and install that package on **target** machine.

Note, that in the above paragraph it is **irrelevant**, whether *cross-compilation* took a place or not: it is possible to build the project on one machine and install it to the other, but similar one, without any cross-compilation.