# CMake adds absolute CMAKE_SYSROOT path to pkg-config pc file

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, pkg-config

I'm trying to cross compile webkit.

In my toolchain file I set:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT "/opt/cross-pi-gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot")
```

During configuration I specify the install dir

```
-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/opt/cross-pi-gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr
```

One of the CMakeLists of the package generate a pkg-config *.PC file which contains:

```
    prefix=/opt/cross-pi-gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot/usr
    exec_prefix=${prefix}
    includedir=${prefix}/include
    libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib    
    Name: wpe-1.0
    Description: The wpe library
    Version: 1.8.0
    Requires: xkbcommon
    Cflags: -I${includedir}/wpe-1.0
    Libs: -L${libdir} -lwpe-1.0
```

This is wrong, the pkg-config cflags should point to /usr on the target not the sysroot path.

The source of the pkgconfig file, which is edited using cmake's configure_file:

```
prefix=@CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX@
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: wpe-@WPE_API_VERSION@
Description: The wpe library
Version: @PROJECT_VERSION@
Requires: xkbcommon
Cflags: -I${includedir}/wpe-@WPE_API_VERSION@
Libs: -L${libdir} -lwpe-@WPE_API_VERSION@
```

Am I using CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX correctly? Or can it be somehow relative CMAKE_SYSROOT?

Comment: Have you checked [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58200855/how-can-i-manage-the-installation-directory-with-cmake-when-cross-compiling) and my answer for it? `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` denotes the path, where the project will be used upon installation. So, if you want to run executable at the **target** machine, your install prefix should be given as  `/usr`, not as `${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr`.

Comment: Ok. So I should keep CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX  set to /usr. 

The project is built using the ninja system. How do I ensure that when running "ninja install" it is copied to the target (${CMAKE_SYSROOT}/usr)?

Comment: Just set environment variable `DESTDIR` to the sysroot (`/opt/cross-pi-gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/sysroot` in your case), so `ninja install` should install the project correctly. See e.g. this example: https://reviews.llvm.org/D41402.